# Parsing a decimal number

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, decimal

Guys, I have a string that contains a decimal number. The problem is, sometimes it is negative and it is stored in accounting format (positive number surrounded by parenthesis). In other words, I got a string like this:

```
string s = "(35.00)";
```

What I'm doing currently is:

```
decimal TheValue = decimal.Parse(s);
```

This value of TheValue should be -35.00. It apparently doesn't know what the parenthesis mean, so its just storing 0 in Thevalue. Anyone know how to make the decimal.Parse() function look for parenthesis?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look at the [`decimal.Parse` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91fwbcsb.aspx) that accepts a [`NumberStyles` enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx). Specifically, you'll need to include `NumberStyles.AllowParentheses`.